# std::fstream saves variable to file wrong

Tags: c++, std, fstream, binaryfiles

Problem solved! Thanks to @ewindes! I may go further with mu project! Bug in Notepad++ Hex Editor Plugin v0.9.5. I open with WinHex and Xplore and see **79 00 00 10**. I trust too match...

I expect see in hex editor **79 00 00 10** but see **79 e1 80 80**. 
Using codeblocks with mingw 5.3.0. Tried visual studio 10 and got same result.

Why can't save variable right?

Code is simple and looks correct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;
const uint32_t uid1 = 0x10000079;

int main()
{
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open("e32.exe", std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::out);
    fs.write((const char*)&uid1, sizeof(uid1));
    fs.close();
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(uid1): " << sizeof(uid1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I play more with code and got very strange results. File "test" contain crap as above:

```
FILE *fp;
if((fp=fopen("test", "wb"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.");
    return 1;
}
char *data = (char *)&uid1;
fwrite(&data[0], 1, 1, fp);
printf("data[0] %x\n", data[0]);
fwrite(&data[1], 1, 1, fp);
printf("data[1] %x\n", data[1]);
fwrite(&data[2], 1, 1, fp);
printf("data[2] %x\n", data[2]);
fwrite(&data[3], 1, 1, fp);
printf("data[3] %x\n", data[3]);
fclose (fp);
```

But uid1 contain valid data:

```
data[0] 79
data[1] 0
data[2] 0
data[3] 10
```

Comment: works for me, as expected. Mac OS clang. Had to fix missing include: `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Tried mingw and visual studio without success. #include <iostream>  present on top and occasionally miscopied.
Glad to hear that it works)

Comment: On a side note, you should generally use `std::ofstream` instead of `std::fstream` with the `out` flag, when you are not reusing the stream for both input and output.

Comment: Maybe endian issues cause that problem?

Comment: Source of errors found: variable uid1. It have values 0x10000079. Look close: if we convert to char array it becomes {10, 00, 00, 79}. __"00"__ breaks everything!
Assign new value to uid1=0x10203079 and all works! I see "79 30 20 10" in hex!
I need some idea how to fix that...

Comment: What hex editor are you using to view the binary file?  It may be lying to you.  Can you try `xxd`?

Comment: @ewindes, hex-editor plugin for notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Bug in Notepad++ Hex Editor Plugin v0.9.5. I open with WinHex and Xplore and see 79 00 00 10. I trust that too match...